# Best parameters of an Optuna multi-objective optimization

Tags: python, optimization, optuna

When performing a single-objective optimization with [Optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), the best parameters of the study are accessible using:

```
import optuna
def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_uniform('x', -10, 10)
    return (x - 2) ** 2

study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)

study.best_params  # E.g. {'x': 2.002108042}
```

If I want to perform a multi-objective optimization, this would be become for example :

```
import optuna
def multi_objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_uniform('x', -10, 10)
    f1 = (x - 2) ** 2
    f2 = -f1
    return f1, f2

study = optuna.create_study(directions=['minimize', 'maximize'])
study.optimize(multi_objective, n_trials=100)
```

This works, but the command `study.best_params` fails with `RuntimeError: The best trial of a 'study' is only supported for single-objective optimization.`

How can I get the best parameters for a multi-objective optimization ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In multi-objective optimization, you often end up with more than one best trial, but rather a set of trials. This set if often referred to as the Pareto front. You can get this Pareto front, or the list of trials, via [`study.best_trials`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.study.Study.html#optuna.study.Study.best_trials), then look at the parameters from each individual trial i.e. `study.best_trials[some_index].params`.

For instance, given your directions of minimizing `f1` and maximizing `f2`, you might end up with a trial that has a small value for `f1` (good) but at the same time small value for `f2` (bad) while another trial might have a large value for both `f1` (bad) and `f2` (good). Both of these trials could be returned from `study.best_trials`.

Comment: Are there any guidlines on how to choose between all the trials in `study.best_trials` ?

Comment: If the number of objectives is either two or three, you can use of [`optuna.visualization.plot_pareto_front`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.0/reference/visualization/generated/optuna.visualization.plot_pareto_front.html) to plot the Pareto front for visual inspection. This requires [plotly](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/). Beyond that, for the time being is outside the scope of Optuna. It is a topic of research in my understanding.

Comment: @Dr.Paprika the answer depends of your problem. You can get the best_params_ and filter on the first value then the second one, or the opposite. You could be more strict on the first parameter but not on the second. Clearly that depends of you and what you want at the end.